# Tkinter combobox showing items imported from CSV into curly brackets

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzDy5.jpg)

[image]Can anyone help me to figure out what I should add to my code below to remove the curly bracket from my tkinter combobox without removing the space in the name of my cities.

Eg. New York showing up as {New York} while Dallas showing up as Dallas in my combobox.

I tried to convert to a string of lists instead of list of tuples but no luck.

Thank you so much.

WW

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

# Creating tkinter window 
window = tk.Tk() 
window.geometry('300x250') 


with open('C:/cities.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile , delimiter=',')
  Tup1 = ()
  for row in spamreader:
      Tup1 = [list(row)for row in spamreader]
      print(Tup1)

 
Combo = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 30, height = 20)
Combo .place(x = 50 , y = 50)
Combo ['values']= Tup1

window.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0jdI.jpg)

Comment: My guess is, `Tup1` is a tuple of tuples. The combobox needs to be given a tuple/list of strings. Please try to [edit]  your example and remove the need for an external file. Instead, h ard-code two or three rows of data in the exact format you're getting from `csv.reader`. You should also do a bit more research; there are a few other questions on this site related to curly braces appearing in data.

Comment: What does `print(Tup1)` produce? Please read [mre].

Answer (score 2):

[image: Combobox]

Please check this out

When you read a CSV file you get a list of rows. Each row is a list of columns. As you have multiple rows here you are recieving nested list in spamreader and hence you were mapping nested list with combobox. Using extend I have added cities to separate list thus eliminating the nested list and mapping cities with combobox thus eliminating the curly brackets

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

# Creating tkinter window 
window = tk.Tk() 
window.geometry('300x250') 

sp=[]
with open('C:/cities.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')  
  for i in spamreader:
      sp.extend(i)
Tup1 = ()
for row in sp:
    Tup1 = [row for row in sp ]
print(Tup1)

 
Combo = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 30, height = 20)
Combo .place(x = 50 , y = 50)
Combo ['values']= Tup1

window.mainloop()
```

**Edit:** Based on comment

Here is the csv format

[image: CSV]

You can use combobox binding to populate value in another combobox based on selection of value from a combobox

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

# Creating tkinter window 
window = tk.Tk() 
window.geometry('300x250') 

states=[]
cities=[]
with open(r'C:\cities.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  next(spamreader,None)
  for i in spamreader:
      states.append(i[1])
      cities.append(i[2])
      
Combo1 = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 30, height = 20)
Combo1 .place(x = 50 , y = 100)
def choose(event):
    city_values=[]
    if(Combo.get() in states):
        city_values.append(cities[states.index(Combo.get())])
    Combo1 ['values']= city_values
 
Combo = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 30, height = 20)
Combo .place(x = 50 , y = 50)
Combo ['values']= states
Combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",choose)

window.mainloop()
```

**Output**

```
Maharashtra-Mumbai
New jersey- Cape May
```

**Edit** Please check snippet based on your last comment.

```
states=[]
cities=[]
with open(r'cities.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  next(spamreader,None)
  for i in spamreader:
      states.append(i[1])
      cities.append(i[2])

stat_City=[[i,j] for i,j in zip(states,cities)]
b = list()
for sublist in stat_City:
    if sublist not in b:
        b.append(sublist)
print(b)
Combo1 = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 30, height = 20)
Combo1 .place(x = 50 , y = 100)

def choose(event):
    city_values=[]
    for i in b:
        if((Combo.get() == i[0]) and (Combo.get() not in city_values)):
            city_values.append(i[1])
    Combo1 ['values']= city_values

c= list()
for i in b:
    if(i[0] not in c):
        c.append(i[0])
Combo = ttk.Combobox(window, width = 30, height = 20)
Combo .place(x = 50 , y = 50)
Combo ['values']= c
Combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",choose)
```

Comment: You might want to explain what `extend()` does

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley @ wwii @ Cool Cloud: Thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: @ Karthik: Awesome !! It works. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Apologies as I feel than I come back on piecemeal basis. My source csv has multiplie columns and notably col 1: Countries, col 2: States, Column 3: Cities, column 4: Districts and so on. All the rows per column are quoted in the combobox while i like only column2: States (without the curly brackets) and without the header of the column. The ultimate idea being to add a second combox listing only the city names when the states is selected in combobox 1. Thank you so much in advance for your further assistance. Best, WW.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your awesome assistance Karthik. It works... definitely big progress here. However where in the CSV list i have several times the same states name quoted in 1 column and several different cities in the other column attached to this states names (but different rows), the combobox 1 reflects several times the same states name and depending on which same states i select in combobox 1, i have a different city name appearing once in the combobox 2.

Comment: its tough or me to understand your csv. @WestWind if you could please attach your csv screenshot like I did it would be much helpful for me

Comment: @WestWind I guess If row count increases still my snippet would work for you.

Comment: @ Karthik. Thank you. I have included a snapshot of my csv above.

Comment: @WestWind Please check the edit. I guess it solves all your problem now. If you have any other doubts, I suggest you to post another query as another question. If you find my answer helpful please accept it as an answer so that it would be helpful for others in future

Comment: @ Karthik, a big thank you ! You're super good (and super nice!!)